# PHP mail() function stop sending mails

Tags: php

Since 3 months. mail() function works everywhere. But yersterday evening... function stops sending email... users can't register, log in, even contact support from our web...

function mail() is on..
but if i check

```
if(mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers))
    {
        echo "Test email send.";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Failed to send.";
    }
```

i got 'Failed to send.'

Any idea what may occur? and how to display error?

because when i using that one:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Have no errors. they are set to on(php.info)

Comment: contact to your server support and open cpanel and manually send mail  from cpanel if mail has been send then issue in your code if not send then contact to server support

Comment: what are the changes you done? normally mail() function is not working

Comment: mail() was on since beginning, just wrote function check it and it was working till yesterday

Comment: @PiotrMirosz open cpanel and send email manually

Comment: i log in to server panel. log in to mail, and send a test mail. Test mail was send.

Comment: i notice that: mail.add_x_header -  are off. it should me off?

Comment: Switch to PHPMailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), you'll have better control of your emails and the related errors.

Comment: Check your MTA's mail log (on a lot of Linux machines with postfix it's `/var/log/mail.log`, but it can vary). A lot of times the MTA will accept your e-mail (hence no errors in your PHP script) but for one reason or another can't actually forward the e-mail (e.g. rate limit exceeded, can't contact remote server, spam filtering, etc). If your MTA knows what happened it'll be in the log.

Comment: check if  it going to SPAM/JUNK or if server is blacklisted or blocked.

Comment: i got 1 result : No DMARC Record found

Comment: hahah after 8 hours of work... i contact serwer provider.... their have issue with system....  omg..